# AWS CDK Creating an aws_codestarnotifications.CfnNotificationRule and setting the targets

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I'm trying to use CDK to create a simple stack in which a codepipeline triggers a lambda.

I have hit a wall trying to set the CfnNotificationRule's targets:

```
THE_PIPELINE_ARN = "arn:aws:codepipeline:eu-west-2:121212121212:the-pipeline"

class ExampleStack(core.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)
    
        notification_topic = aws_sns.Topic(self, "TheNotificationTopic")

        notification_rule = aws_codestarnotifications.CfnNotificationRule(
            self,
            "StackStatusChangeNotificationRule",
            detail_type="FULL",
            event_type_ids=[
                "codepipeline-pipeline-action-execution-succeeded",
                "codepipeline-pipeline-action-execution-failed",
            ],
            name="TheStackCodeStarNotificationsNotificationRule",
            resource=THE_PIPELINE_ARN,
            targets= # what goes here?
            )
```

I want the notifications to go to the SNS topic defined by notification_topic.

I think this should be a aws_cdk.aws_codestarnotifications.TargetProperty based on
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codestarnotifications.CfnNotificationRule.TargetProperty.html
but the type doesn't seem to exist for Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok finally figured it out, TargetProperty is a nested class of CfnNotificationRule, not a class in the module (contrary to the documentation). So the correct code looks like:

```
THE_PIPELINE_ARN = "arn:aws:codepipeline:eu-west-2:121212121212:the-pipeline"

class ExampleStack(core.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)
    
        notification_topic = aws_sns.Topic(self, "TheNotificationTopic")

        notification_rule = aws_codestarnotifications.CfnNotificationRule(
            self,
            "StackStatusChangeNotificationRule",
            detail_type="FULL",
            event_type_ids=[
                "codepipeline-pipeline-action-execution-succeeded",
                "codepipeline-pipeline-action-execution-failed",
            ],
            name="TheStackCodeStarNotificationsNotificationRule",
            resource=THE_PIPELINE_ARN,
            targets= [aws_codestarnotifications.CfnNotificationRule.TargetProperty(
                      target_type="SNS",
                      target_address=notification_topic.topic_arn),
                     ]
            )
```

Comment: Thanks to this answer I was able to use chatbot and use Slack integration! Thanks